# Nested mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, nested-data

I have a data set where we have collected fish for behavioural experiments from different areas and within each area we have selected a clear water site and a eutrophied site. We then brought the fish to lab - all fish were used only once, they built a nest and that was it. What we wanted to know was if habitat type (clear or eutrophied) affected the nest building.
This is the original model (for example for nest weight, male weight as a covariate):

```
m1 <- lme(NestW ~ Habitat + MaleW, random = (~1|Area/Site))
```

The trouble is `dfs` - they are way too high and reflecting the amount of fish used, not the areas, which we would want to be the unit of replication here. So, how to fix this? (adding Habitat to the random effect does not help)

Comment: Could you give a few details about the data? Maybe the first few rows? Is it one fish per nest? In your model, since Nest weight is the response, your sample size is the number of nests and the df's go down from there.

Comment: In any case, to test for the impact of habitat, you would fit 2 models - one with Habitat and 1 without - then compare with a likelihood ratio test - and the degrees of freedom would be 1. Don't do a t-test on the coefficient of Habitat; you need to compare models.

Comment: And while the experimental unit is the site, the sampling unit is the nest - since you are measuring nest weights and fish weights. I don't think there is anything to fix here. That's' what lme does with random effects. What matters is that you do the right significance test.